# Symfony Form - Value Object, DataMappers and EventSubscriber

Tags: forms, symfony

I am having trouble to dynamically modify field in my form using DataMapper and EventSubscriber.

Here is my form:

- A select field
- A field which will be modified by the select field above.

I am using an EventSubscriber to dynamically modify my form using AJAX.
And a DataMapper to map my Value Object to the form and vice-versa.

So when i do that:

```
$moneyForm = $this->createForm(MoneyType::class);
```

Everything is working. But when i pass my Value Object as data class:

```
$money     = new Money(199, 'USD');
$moneyForm = $this->createForm(MoneyType::class, $money);
```

I got an error here:

```
   public function mapDataToForms($viewData, $forms)
    {
        $forms = iterator_to_array($forms);

        $forms['money']->setData($viewData ? $viewData->money() : 0);
        $forms['currency']->setData($viewData ? $viewData->currency() : 'USD');
    }
```

This error says that: **Notice: Undefined index:**.

It seems like the form has been replaced by a new one and i don't understand it.
I don't know why when i use a data mapper alone, or event subscriber alone everything is working.

But when i try to mix, both of them i got this error.

Does anyone have a clue of what's going on here?

Thank you

Comment: could you describe the main idea of that? It seems that you are complicating the task. Also, can you pass $money's value to MoneyType as integer and set currency as "currency" parameter for the field https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/money.html#currency?

Comment: I would like to create a custom form field type based on a value object (the value object will be the data class of this form type).

This form type will have 2 field. 

A select field and an other field depending on the select above.

Comment: please show your form type (MoneyType), your DataTransformer and the value object class. I assume that the transformer might be completely unnecessary, depending on your value object. Certainly, If you'd just use standard getters and setters.